# How to input a procedure into another procedure

Tags: vb.net

I have a code like below. This is main logic function and I'd like to insert different procedures in that procedure. So is it a way or solution to do that. I marked with **.

```
Public Shared Sub CheckListSubstrs(ByVal Substrs As IScrNamedObjectList, **mySub(Substr As IScrSubstructure)**)
    Dim Substr As IScrSubstructure = Nothing
    Dim nSubstr As Integer = Nothing
    nSubstr = Substrs.count
    If nSubstr > 0 Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To nSubstr - 1
            Substr = CType(Substrs.item(i), IScrSubstructure)
            **mySub(Substr As IScrSubstructure)**
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

I have different types of sub/func procedures and all of them uses `Substr As IScr as Substructure` as their input so I'd like to insert them dynamically and call them for different classes, modules.

**EDIT**

I have to clarify my problem more specific to clear conversations.

This is my class with all values.

```
    Option Explicit On
    Option Strict On
    Imports simpackcomslvLib
    Public Class Substr
        Public Shared Sub CheckListSubstrs(ByVal Substrs As IScrNamedObjectList, ByVal dgv As DataGridView, SourceType As ****)
            Dim nSubstr As Integer = Nothing
            nSubstr = Substrs.count
            If nSubstr > 0 Then
                For i As Integer = 0 To nSubstr - 1
                    Dim Substr As IScrSubstructure = CType(Substrs.item(i), IScrSubstructure)

                  'Procedure comes here according to element type for example listing bodies
'  CheckListBodies(Substr.getBodyList(False), DataGridView2)
'or if i list forces
  'CheckListForces(Substr.getForceList(False), DataGridView3)


                    'Recursive usage function to get lower substructures information you can think there's a cascaded structure of substructures
                    CheckListSubstrs(Substrs:=Substr.getSubstrList(False), ProcedureForElementType As ****)
                Next
            End If
        End Sub
        Private Shared Sub CheckListBodies(ByVal Bodies As IScrNamedObjectList, ByVal dgv As DataGridView)
            Dim nBody As Integer
            nBody = Bodies.count
            For i As Integer = 0 To nBody - 1
                Dim Body As IScrBody = CType(Bodies.item(i), IScrBody)
                dgv.Rows.Add(Body.fullName)
            Next
        End Sub
        Private Shared Sub CheckListForces(ByVal Forces As IScrNamedObjectList, ByVal dgv As DataGridView)
            Dim nForce As Integer
            nForce = Forces.count
            For i As Integer = 0 To nForce - 1
                Dim Force As IScrForce = CType(Forces.item(i), IScrForce)
                dgv.Rows.Add(Force.fullName)
            Next
        End Sub
        Public Shared Sub RunTheCodeforBodies()
            CheckListSubstrs(Mdl.getSubstrList(False), DataGridView2, getBodyList)
        End Sub
        Public Shared Sub RunTheCodeforForces()
            CheckListSubstrs(Mdl.getSubstrList(False), DataGridView3, getForceList)
        End Sub
    End Class
```

As I showed two examples here, I'm listing different types approx. 30 types. I'm using com-interface and this *Iscr* types of classes from 3rd part software which I'm connecting.

So all of properties belongs to substructures and I only want to change function element type and output datagridview.

Comment: You should look into delegates, which are objects that refer to methods. They are the .NET equivalent of function pointers from C/C++.  There are numerous existing delegate types and you can declare your own too, but you probably ought to use the `Action` and `Func` delegates in most general-purpose situations. You use an `Action` to refer to a `Sub` and a `Func` to refer to a `Function` and they can have anything up to (I think) 16 parameters.  You should start by reading the appropriate documentation and then go from there.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean when you say that you _"only want to change function element type"_? What exactly is _"function element type"_? Do you mean the type(s) of the parameter(s) passed to the function?

Comment: For example if i run CheckListSubstrs(Mdl.getSubstrList(False), DataGridView2, getBodyList) i want my CheckListSubstrs procedure runs/uses CheckListBodies(Substr.getBodyList(False), DataGridView2) only. If i run             CheckListSubstrs(Mdl.getSubstrList(False), DataGridView3, getForceList)
 it uses CheckListSubstrs procedure uses CheckListForces procedure only.

Comment: @VisualVincent sorry i forgot the mention you. My description above.

Comment: You can use the [`AddressOf` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/addressof-operator) to get a pointer to either of your existing methods. As for which type to use for your parameters, you can either use an [`Action(Of T1, T2)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-2) (or how many parameters you need), or do like Jimi suggested and declare your own delegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have existing methods that should elaborate a **`IScrSubstructure`** object and, as you say, all methods heve the same *signature*, you can use a [method delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/delegates/) with that same signature and use it as a parameter of the `CheckListSubstrs` sub.

A simulation, with some objects that can be used for testing:

```
Public Structure IScrSubstructure
    Public value1 As String
    Public value2 As Integer
End Structure

Public Class IScrNamedObjectList
    Inherits List(Of IScrSubstructure)
End Class

Public Delegate Sub ScrSubstructureDelegate(ByVal Substr As IScrSubstructure)

Public Shared Sub CheckListSubstrs(ByVal Substrs As IScrNamedObjectList, MyDelegate As ScrSubstructureDelegate)

    If Substrs?.Count > 0 Then
        For Each item As IScrSubstructure In Substrs
            MyDelegate(item)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Now, your `CheckListSubstrs` method has a parameter:

```
MyDelegate As ScrSubstructureDelegate
```

you can pass any method that matches that signature:

```
ByVal Substr As IScrSubstructure
```

If you try to pass a method that doesn't match the delegate signature, the code will not compile.

So, lets build a couple of methods with these characteristics and call the `CheckListSubstrs` method using both methods as the **`MyDelegate`** parameter:

```
Public Sub MyIScrSub(ByVal Substr1 As IScrSubstructure)
    'Do something with Substr1
    Console.WriteLine("MyIScrSub Value1: {0}, MyIScrSub Value2: {1}", Substr1.value1, Substr1.value2)
End Sub

Public Sub MyOtherIScrSub(ByVal AnotherSubscr As IScrSubstructure)
    'Do something with AnotherSubscr
    Console.WriteLine("MyOtherIScrSub Value1: {0}, MyOtherIScrSub Value2: {1}", AnotherSubscr.value1, AnotherSubscr.value2)
End Sub
```

Now you can call `CheckListSubstrs` passing both **`MyIScrSub`** and **`MyOtherIScrSub`** methods as delegate:

```
Dim ScrList As IScrNamedObjectList = New IScrNamedObjectList()
ScrList.Add(New IScrSubstructure() With {.value1 = "Value1", .value2 = 1})
ScrList.Add(New IScrSubstructure() With {.value1 = "Value2", .value2 = 2})
ScrList.Add(New IScrSubstructure() With {.value1 = "Value3", .value2 = 3})

CheckListSubstrs(ScrList, AddressOf MyIScrSub)
CheckListSubstrs(ScrList, AddressOf MyOtherIScrSub)
```

As an note, in the `CheckListSubstrs` sub I wrote:

```
If Substrs?.Count > 0 Then
     (...)
End If
```

so you can handle null values for the **`IScrNamedObjectList`** parameter:
(this syntax requires `VB.Net 14` or newer)

```
CheckListSubstrs(nothing, AddressOf MyIScrSub)
```

but you could also write:

```
If Substrs IsNot Nothing Then
     (...)
End If
```

Comment: thanks for the great desc. i'm working on it for an hour to implement and looking forward to see results.

Comment: Note that the `MyDelegate As ScrSubstructureDelegate` action or method delegate can also be a Proxy method. You can use this proxy as the delegate. The proxy can the call any number of other methods using the provided parameter(s), possibly performing some pre-processing for each other method. I use this kind of procedure quite ofter to process long running queues splitting the workload between different Tasks.

Comment: In fact i didnt succeeded yet, and want to clearify my problem with edits. If you have a chance it would be perfect to see my updated explanations above. I'd like to avoid misunderstandings maybe it'd help more to imagine.